# Firebase gets invalid email error message

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-authentication, email-verification

I get this error after creating user and tried to send verification email always get this error for invalid email, while the email is registered and valid.

> Optional(Error Domain=FIRAuthErrorDomain Code=17008 "Missing sender" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Missing sender, error_name=ERROR_INVALID_EMAIL})

```
Auth.auth().currentUser?.sendEmailVerification(completion: { (error) in
    if error != nil {
        print(error.debugDescription)

        let alert = UIAlertController(title: NSLocalizedString("Error", comment: "Error"), message: NSLocalizedString("Unable to send verification, Please check provided email and try again.", comment: "Unable to send verification, Please check provided email and try again."), preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: { _ in
        }))
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        AppDelegate.instance().dismissActivityIndicatos()
        return
    }
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

It says `missing sender`. This could be an issue in your email template. Did you customize the email sender field in the Firebase Console by any chance?

Comment: Yes, for email verification i did customize the sender field. Should it be left empty?

Comment: Yeah thanks that was the issue, but to configure the sender what do i do because the verification emails takes forever to reach my users.

Comment: That is a separate issue (email delays). If you are experiencing that, reach out to Firebase Support: https://firebase.google.com/support/ As for sender email, you should be able to configure it in the Firebase Console Email templates section.